# How to read/write key-value pairs in Elasticache using Boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-elasticache

I need my python code to read/write key-value pair to AWS Elasticache Redis, for which I plan to use the Boto3 SDK. However, in the docs, I do not see a put/get API for elasticache client.

Reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticache.html

Is it possible to do this with Boto3? If yes, looks like it does not have a straight forward API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `boto3` library is used for programmatically managing AWS infrastructure resources, e.g. creating an ElastiCache cluster, tagging an existing cluster, modifying security groups etc.

It is not a general-purpose Redis SDK. You can use a Python package such as [redis](https://pypi.org/project/redis/) for that.

Comment: I wonder why Boto3's S3 or DynamoDB clients allow to insert and retrieve data?

Comment: Good question, I can see where you're coming from. DynamoDB is a 100% AWS service. There were no existing client SDKs for talking to DynamoDB. Whereas Redis, Elasticache, Elasticsearch, MySQL, Oracle etc. are all mature, third-party technologies with their own SDKs, client APIs etc. AWS provides SDKs to manage them but, in general, not to actually interact with their native APIs. In the case of DynamoDB, I guess that AWS decided it made more sense to include the management SDK and the data SDK together.